# RSS Feed issue- All expected items not seems to be shown on page

Tags: rss

We are facing one in RSS-Feed on CD, some items on CD have publish date but they are not listed in RSS-feed page. We have custom implementation for feed but it only removes item if it is null or don't have publish date.

1. Any idea/clue  why some items have not shown up in Feed although they have latest publish date, also it comes using query given for RSS-feed
2. Although we have Feeds.MaximumItemsInFeed to 100, but it only shows 68 items and when i increased it to 200 then it displays 100 items
3. Do we have control on Sorting of Feed items.

[image]

Comment: Can you share code from your custom implementation?

Comment: @MichaelWest updated desc with code snippet

Answer (score 2):

It had issue as was fetching unwanted items as well i.e. item having publish date null.
So although set Feeds.MaximumItemsInFeed to 100, it got filtered at code level so reduced the total number of records in RSS.

After altering RSS query to fetch only those records which have some publish date have resolved the issue, e.g. given below:

```
query:/sitecore/content/My Site/Home//*[@Publish Date > '' ]
```

Now it is fetching all eligible records so don't alter the count on feed and include other eligible records in it.